# Expiring the Sprockets cache from Rails (not Rake)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a special scenario where if a specific file changes, **I need to expire the Sprockets cache (all stylesheets) from Ruby/Rails**.

My (failed) approach so far is to prepend `dependency_fresh?` and attempt to expire the index.

```
module SprocketsAssetWrapper
  def dependency_fresh?(environment, dep)

    if <file is changed>

      # Attempt to expire the Sprocket's Environment
      # Errors with "can't modify immutable index"
      environment.send(:expire_index!)

      <reset file as unchanged>
    end

    super environment, dep
  end
end

class Sprockets::Asset
  prepend SprocketsAssetWrapper
end
```

As commented, `environment.send(:expire_index!)` errors with `can't modify immutable index`.

Any help would be great.  I'm on Rails 4.1.4 and have `sprockets-rails` installed.

Thanks,

Erik